# how to get unique values and its count in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am new to python programming.

I want to loop through each user and get unique countries and its counts.

Here's the input data i have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','101','102','102','102'],'Country':['India,Brazil','India','India,Brazil,Japan','India,Brazil','India']})
```

wanted output here

[image: wanted output]

Thanks

Comment: The duplicate doesn't particularly answer the question, but there is a dupe. Anyway, use `df.set_index('User').Country.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts()`

Comment: Thanks so much @coldspeed . if you dont mind how to repeat the user id value to all the rows?

Comment: Add `.reset_index()`

Comment: thanks..df.set_index('User id').Country.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns = {'level_1' : 'Country',0:'ctry_count'}) is there way to avoid rename statement here?